# Integral over unit disk of $log|z-w|^2/(z-z_1)(\bar{z}-\bar{w}_1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration, greens-function, singular-integrals

I am trying to compute the following integral: 
$$\int_D \frac{\log|z-w|^2}{(z-z_1)(\bar{z}-\bar{w}_1)} d\bar{z}dz. $$
Here $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z|<1\} $ and $w,z_1,w_1 \in D$ are parameters.  The integral converges if the parameters are pairwise distinct, which I assume.

I can compute integrals of this type if the numerator is holomorphic by expanding it in power series, and one can reduce to monomials 
$$\int_D \frac{z^k}{(z-z_1)(\bar{z}-\bar{w}_1)} d\bar{z}dz $$

that I know how to do. However, this method does not work for this integral. I have tried to use complex analysis by writing the absolute value as $(z-w)(\bar{z}-\bar{w})$, introducing a cut from $z_0 \in \partial D$ to $w$, but then one does not get a power series expansion valid on the disk.

I also tried to exploit the fact that $\log|z-w|^2$ is the 2D Green's function (up to a constant), but I was not successful with this idea.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle something like this? Any help is appreciated.